# XML Validation XSD problem

Tags: xml, xsd

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <ac code="B2" auto="1">
        <fee>
            <if country="RU">35e 50e 50e 80e 15e 10e</if>
            <else>10e</else>
        </fee>
        <comission>
            <if country="RU">3%</if>
            <else>5%</else>
        </comission>
    </ac>
</data>
```

**Schema**:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <xs:element name="data" type="data"/>
 <xs:complexType name="data">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="ac" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ac"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="ac">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="fee" type="feecomiss"/>
   <xs:element name="comission" type="feecomiss"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="auto" type="xs:decimal"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="feecomiss">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="if" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="if"/>
   <xs:element name="else" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="if">
   <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string" />
 </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

This scheme does not validate: (

But if i insert an element inside "if" in xml

```
<if country="RU"><lol>35e 50e 50e 80e 15e 10e</lol></if>
```

and fix schema

```
 <xs:complexType name="if">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="lol" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string" />
 </xs:complexType>
```

That code is valid

How can I fix this?thank you!!! Sorry for bad english

Comment: -1: I tried myself to edit the title of your question to be more specific to find out that a similar problem [has already been solved](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20926860/413020). I don't think this kind of "solve my code" questions adds anything to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `<xsd:simplecontent>` element here.

```
 <xs:complexType name="if">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
 </xs:complexType>
```

You can find more information on the [XSD tutorial page for text-only elements](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_text.asp). Basically what's wrong is that `if` isn't defined to be able to have text content because it's a complex type. You use `simpleContent` to allow it to contain text.