# XML validation against XSD: Element must have no character or element information item

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Why does my XML not validate against the following XSD?

My XML file is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--DOCTYPE jocuri SYSTEM "JocuriIrimiaRaduSilviu.dtd"--> 
<!-- se decomenteaza linia de mai sus doar pentru validarea DTD-ului-->
<jocuri>
        <joc>
        <numeJoc>FIFA14</numeJoc>
        <developerJoc>EA SPORTS</developerJoc>
        <publisherJoc>EA</publisherJoc>
        <siteOficialJoc>www.easports.com</siteOficialJoc>
        <genJoc gen="MISC">SPORTS</genJoc>
        <anAparitieJoc>2013</anAparitieJoc>
        <ratingPEGI rating="3">3</ratingPEGI>
        <scorMetacritic>90</scorMetacritic>
        <pretJoc>60</pretJoc>
        <varianta platforma="NONE">XONE</varianta>
        <numarBucati>3</numarBucati>
    </joc>
    <joc>
        <numeJoc>FIFA14</numeJoc>
        <developerJoc>EA SPORTS</developerJoc>
        <publisherJoc>EA</publisherJoc>
        <siteOficialJoc>www.easports.com</siteOficialJoc>
        <genJoc gen="MISC">SPORTS</genJoc>
        <anAparitieJoc>2013</anAparitieJoc>
        <ratingPEGI rating="3">3</ratingPEGI>
        <scorMetacritic>90</scorMetacritic>
        <pretJoc>60</pretJoc>
        <varianta platforma="NONE">PS4</varianta>
        <numarBucati>3</numarBucati>
    </joc>
</jocuri>
```

And i am using the following XSD :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="jocuri">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>DOCTYPE jocuri SYSTEM "JocuriIrimiaRaduSilviu.dtd" se decomenteaza linia de mai sus doar pentru validarea DTD-ului</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="joc" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="numeJoc"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="developerJoc"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="publisherJoc"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="siteOficialJoc"/>
              <xs:element name="genJoc">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="gen" use="required">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="MISC"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="FPS"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="TPS"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="ACTION"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="RPG"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="MMORPG"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="RTS"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="RACING"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="SIMULATOR"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="SPORTS"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                 </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="anAparitieJoc"/>
              <xs:element name="ratingPEGI">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                            <xs:attribute name="rating" use="required">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="12"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="15"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="17"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="18"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="scorMetacritic"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="pretJoc"/>
              <xs:element name="varianta">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                            <xs:attribute name="platforma" use="required">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="NONE"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="PS3"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="X360"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="PS4"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="XONE"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="PC"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="WII"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="WIIU"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="numarBucati"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I cannot validate the XML against the XSD for some reason. They both work validated on their own on the site that I am using.

I am using http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.Ushm77Sn4gB

Comment: The site you are using currently provides a very specific reason why it does not validate: _Not valid.
Error - Line 10, 43: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 43; cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'genJoc' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty._ That is the reason.

Comment: Two remarks: 1. why are you using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8? 2. You should bind your elements to your schema: `<jocuri xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="JocuriIrimiaRaduSilviu.xsd">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this,

```
  <xs:element name="genJoc">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="gen" use="required">
```

for this one

```
  <xs:element name="genJoc">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:attribute name="gen" use="required">
```

in your XSD.

Comment: Roger that. On it, as we speak.I will see what happens.Later update: it works, dude. Thanks a milion times, even. :)